# Dask @delayed converts dataframes to pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dask, dask-distributed, dask-delayed

I have this code that calls a dask `@delayed` function that takes N dask dataframes as input and returns a dask dataframe as output.

There are two problems (1) inside the function the type of the dataframe is pandas instead of dask, and (2) when I get the result of the function, it's also pandas instead of dask.

What is the logic behind `@delayed` to get as input pandas dataframes instead of dask? I need to work only with dask dataframes.

This is the code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'height':  [6.21, 5.12, 5.85, 5.78, 5.98],
    'weight': [150, 126, 133, 164, 203]
})

df_dask = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=2)


@delayed
def some_function(*b):
    print('type b[0]: ' + str(type(b[0])) )
    ddf = b[0]
    return ddf

ddfout = some_function(df_dask, df_dask, df_dask)

computed = ddfout.compute()
>>> type b[0]: <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'> # this should be dask dataframe

type(computed)
>>> pandas.core.frame.DataFrame
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way to get column `0` of dask dataframe `ddf` is:

```
ddf[0]
```

There is no need for delayed here, the API already provides lazy operations over all the pandas methods that are supported (most of them).

Delayed is for arbitrary operations on constants and other delayed values, *not* dask collections like the dataframe.

See documentation: https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/delayed-best-practices.html#don-t-call-dask-delayed-on-other-dask-collections ; you *probably* wanted `ddf.map_partitions`.

Comment: Yes, I know that I don't need delayed in this code, it is simplified as an example. Does this mean that I cannot use a dask dataframe as input parameter in a delayed function? map_partitions works for each dataframe, and what I need is a function that will process N dataframes where N is a variable number.

Comment: Do your actions on each dataframe in a loop - these are kazy - and then pass them all into a single call do `dask.compute()`. Don't mix delayed and the collections.